# send database data to others pc in one network

Tags: php, curl

I want to ask about curl php...

I want to grab data from database and send to other pc using php curl and save it into plain text. but my problem is, the system don't sent data from database but just send name that i declare for data. i use fedora platform... Actually I'm beginner in curl php...

here my code... send.php

```
   <?php

   $servername = "yusufpsm";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "921217";
   $db_name = "squid";


   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

   // Check connection
   if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  echo "Connected successfully\n";

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  $sql = "SELECT domain_name, domain_content, reason FROM domain";

  $domain= $_POST['domain_name'];
  $content= $_POST['domain_content'];
  $reason = $_POST['reason'];

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
  {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

  {


  $curlHandle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, '192.168.100.11/update.php');
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,                    'domain_name='.$domain.'domain_content='.$content. 'reason='.$reason);
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  if (!curl_exec($curlHandle)) {
  echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($curlHandle);
  }
  else {
  echo 'everything was successful';
  } 
  }
  } 
   else 
  {
  echo "0 results";
  }



   curl_close($curlHandle) ;

   mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

and here update.php

```
    <?php


    $domain_name = $_POST['domain_name'];
    $domain_content = $_POST['domain_content'];
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];

    chmod("/var/www/html/newfile.txt",0777);
    $myfile = fopen("/var/www/html/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open   file!");
    $txt = $domain_name;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
    $txt = $domain_content;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
    $txt = $reason;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

   ?>
```

Comment: I honestly don't think sending sending MySQL results via text isn't good.
You might want to send it in a JSON format, then receive it and parse it.

Comment: i newbie in php coding actually... i student from networking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try following code  



   <?php

       $servername = "yusufpsm";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "921217";
       $db_name = "squid";


       // Create connection
       $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

       // Check connection
       if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }
      echo "Connected successfully\n";

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      $sql = "SELECT domain_name, domain_content, reason FROM domain";

     /* $domain= $_POST['domain_name'];
      $content= $_POST['domain_content']; // don't know what is this
      $reason = $_POST['reason'];*/

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
      {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

      {

     $domain= $row['domain_name'];
      $content= $row['domain_content']; // get values row-wise from db
      $reason = $row['reason'];

      $curlHandle = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, '192.168.100.11/update.php');
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,                    'domain_name='.$domain.'&domain_content='.$content. '&reason='.$reason);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      if (!curl_exec($curlHandle)) {
      echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($curlHandle);
      }
      else {
      echo 'everything was successful';
      } 
      }
      } 
       else 
      {
      echo "0 results";
      }



       curl_close($curlHandle) ;

       mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: just add & sign ?? @Transformer

Comment: your syntax is in-correct at mentioned  line if you have multiple value than you have to separate them by & sign, have u tried that or not ?

Comment: i have try that syntax, but still can't get data from database @transformer

Comment: i made some changes to get data from db check it

Comment: in my database have 6 rows, but it only save 6th row in plain text @transformer

Comment: use "a" insted of "w" in your  fopen("/var/www/html/newfile.txt", "w") "a" stand for append mode and w for write mode   you got 6 row but older rows are replaced every time this is why u get last row in your text file

Comment: how can i add more ip address on this code? because i want data can be send more than 1 pc... @Transformer

Comment: i already use "a" in coding... yes i get all data in plain text. but when i try again and again, same data will rewrite again..